# Why won't web page won't give data to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, screen-scraping

I would like to get this nice table-like data from a website (https://app.zerion.io/0x6ef9dca82362509cd878051d1fdc6db12dda2989/overview). (In particular, the table with xpath is `/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div`)

In Excel 365, I make a web query (get data / from web) to that address, and it just gives Excel a big "NA" with empty results. (Same happens in Google Sheets with `importhtml` function). Is there something about this website that causes it to refuse table scraping? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Ironically if I click the link I can't see anything either. Just blank white page.

Comment: Could it be that you are logged into the site with say chrome browser and the personalised link only works if you are logged in? Perhaps try logging in first using old Internet Explorer or the internal Excel browser (which is IE I think, but perhaps the cookies aren't shared) or lastly try Edge.